# Same script file showing multiple times in process list

Tags: php, cron, centos, fpm

I have a PHP script which runs on a cron every 10 minutes - when the script finishes it seems to still remain in the running processes until a restart.

For example if I run

```
ps aux | grep -i scriptName
```

I get

```
root       684  0.2  0.0 383884 23188 ?        Ss   Feb27   0:07 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root       846  0.9  0.0 383880 23124 ?        Ss   Feb27   4:39 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root       925  0.5  0.0 383868 23136 ?        Ss   Feb27   1:39 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root      1524  0.2  0.0 383884 23176 ?        Ss   Feb27   0:07 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root      1632  0.6  0.0 383868 23132 ?        Ss   Feb27   1:45 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root      1750  0.9  0.0 383880 23116 ?        Ss   Feb27   4:32 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root      2172  0.2  0.0 383884 23184 ?        Ss   Feb27   0:06 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
root      2289  0.5  0.0 383868 23140 ?        Ss   Feb27   1:33 /usr/bin/php -q /path/to/scriptName
```

How can I get these to clean up once they have run?

I have other scripts which run on cron which do not seem to do this - this is the only one which does.

At the moment there are 100 of these running and I am worried they are going to cause a resource hit and cause issues or a performance problem.

Comment: How long does it take for each script to run individually? if it takes more than 10 minutes, maybe the previous one disturbs the later one. Also, can you add your crontab setting to run your script?

Comment: Check the script. And be sure it run properly for less than 10 minutes. Otherwise add some control to avoid multiply copies